Why am I getting InvalidParameterValueException if I call quicksight:UpdateAnalysisPermissions immediately after creating a user?
I am trying to write a test suite for a QuickSight user management script, but most of the time when I try to call quicksight:UpdateAnalysisPermissions, I get an InvalidParameterValueException.
Before and after each test, I delete all QuickSight users that may have been created by previous tests, and then create all necessary users as a part of each test.
When creating and deleting users, I have implemented functions to wait until users have been confirmed to be created or deleted respectively using exponential backoff, but the problem persists.
Here is an example that results in the observed issue.
You may need to run it several times before the bug appears.
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    import botostubs

import backoff
import boto3
import json

region: str = 'us-east-1'

quicksight = boto3.client('quicksight', region_name = region)

account_id: str = '124567910111'
namespace: str = 'default'
user_id: str = 'test_user_id'
user_email: str = 'test@test.com'
user_role_name: str = 'test_user_role_name'
user_role_arn: str = f'arn:aws:iam::{account_id}:role/{user_role_name}'
user_name: str = f'{user_role_name}/{user_id}'
user_arn: str = f'arn:aws:quicksight:{region}:{account_id}:user/{namespace}/{user_name}'
analysis_id: str = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
backoff_time: float = 10

analysis_permissions = [
    "quicksight:RestoreAnalysis",
    "quicksight:UpdateAnalysisPermissions",
    "quicksight:DeleteAnalysis",
    "quicksight:QueryAnalysis",
    "quicksight:DescribeAnalysisPermissions",
    "quicksight:DescribeAnalysis",
    "quicksight:UpdateAnalysis",
]

@backoff.on_exception(backoff.expo, Exception, max_time = backoff_time)
def get_qs_user(quicksight, user_name: str): # type: (botostubs.QuickSight, str) -> botostubs.QuickSight.DescribeUserResponse
    return quicksight.describe_user(
        AwsAccountId = account_id,
        Namespace = namespace,
        UserName = user_name,
    )

# Create a new user
response = quicksight.register_user(
    AwsAccountId = account_id,
    Namespace = namespace,
    IdentityType = 'IAM',
    IamArn = user_role_arn,
    SessionName = user_id,
    Email = user_email,
    UserRole = 'AUTHOR',
    ExternalLoginFederationProviderType = 'COGNITO',
    ExternalLoginId = user_email,
)

print(f'register_user succeeded: {json.dumps(response, default = str, indent = 4)}\n')

try:
    
    # Verify the user exists
    response = get_qs_user(quicksight, user_name)
    print(f'verified user was created: {json.dumps(response, default = str, indent = 4)}\n')

    # Allow new user to access analysis
    response = quicksight.update_analysis_permissions(
        AwsAccountId = account_id,
        AnalysisId = analysis_id,
        GrantPermissions = [{
            'Principal': user_arn,
            'Actions': analysis_permissions,
        }]
    )
    print(f'update_analysis_permissions succeeded: {json.dumps(response, default = str, indent = 4)}\n')

except Exception as e:
    print(f'update_analysis_permissions failed: {str(e)}\n') # Fails here
    pass

finally:

    # Delete user
    response = quicksight.delete_user(
        UserName = user_name,
        AwsAccountId = account_id,
        Namespace = namespace,
    )

    print(f'delete_user succeeded: {json.dumps(response, default = str, indent = 4)}')



